# JAVA: Why is eclipse calling my second else-if statement a "dead code"?

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I am writing a code in JAVA on Eclipse IDE, and I am having a problem with my if-else statement. From my third outer "if", I have two "else-if" blocks, and Eclipse is calling my second "else-if" a dead code and skips it -- I checked it using Eclipse debugger, but I don't know why. Eclipse keeps suggesting me to delete the second else-if statement, which significantly changes my code.

Please let me know if there is any other information that I can add, and thanks in advance for all the help!

Here is the code:

```
public static void eachCycleUni (Queue processes, int numProcesses, Process[] allProcesses, Process[] original) {   
    Queue<Process> readyProcesses = new LinkedList<Process>();      //Stores processes that are ready

    for (int p = 0; p < allProcesses.length; p++) {
        Process currentProcess = allProcesses[p];
        while (terminatedProcesses != numProcesses) {
            //Nothing --> Nothing or Nothing --> currentRunning
            if (currentRunning == null && currentBlocked == null) {
                ....
            }
            //currentRunning --> --, or currentRunning --> currentBlocked, or currentRunning --> terminated
            else if (currentRunning.CPUburstRemaining != 0 && currentBlocked == null) {
                ...
            }
            //THIS ELSE-IF
            else if (currentBlocked.IOburstRemaining != 0 && currentRunning == null) {
                ...
            }
            cycleNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dead code means that condition never execute.

Comment: Could you add a comment in the code which `if-else` you mean? Unrelated to your current issue: Strings are immutable, so change the `==` checks on Strings to `.equals` (i.e. `thisProcess.state.equals("blocked")` instead of `thisProcess.state == "blocked"`)

Comment: I commented "//THIS ELSE-IF" - just edited.

Comment: I tried to cut down the code by erasing irrelevant information - just edited.

Comment: This is extremely ugly code, please split that  into 3-10 functions and maybe you will see the error easily :P (Hint since your are using eclipse, you can use refactor utilities  :) )

Answer (score 5):

The relevant if and else-if checks are:

```
if (currentRunning == null && currentBlocked == null) {
   ...
}
else if (currentRunning.CPUburstRemaining != 0 && currentBlocked == null) {
   ...
}
else if (currentBlocked.IOburstRemaining != 0 && currentRunning == null) {
   ...
}
```

Your first if-checks will check that both `currentRunning` and `currentBlocked` are both `null`.

If this is not the case, you will check if `currentBlocked` is `null` and using `currentRunning.CPUburstRemaining` implicitly means `currentRunning` cannot be `null` (otherwise a `NullPointerException` would have been given).

After these two checks we therefore know that `currentRunning` can never be `null` anymore, because it would either have entered the first `if`-statement, or would have given a `NullPointerException` at the `currentRunning.CPUburstRemaining` in the first `else if`-block.

Because of that, your `&& currentRunning == null` part of your `else if (currentBlocked.IOburstRemaining != 0 && currentRunning == null)` will ***always*** be falsey, so the IDE sees this as dead code.